# handling of unstructured data in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to read a unstructured csv file using pandas `read_csv()`. The problem is some of the files have rows with extra columns as shown below in the sample input.

sample input:

```
col0,col1,col2
a,b,c
a,b,c,d
a,b,c 
a,b,c,d
```

While handling these kind of files the program throws some ParseError

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 3, saw 4
```

sample output :

```
col0 | col1 | col2 | col3
a    | b    | c    | NaN
a    | b    | c    | d
a    | b    | c    | NaN
a    | b    | c    | d
```

I don't want to ignore the lines with `error_bad_lines = False` parameter in pandas `read_csv()`.

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know max possible number of columns?

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is preprocessing first and find max number of separators, and set parameter `names` by `range`:

```
path_csv = 'file.csv'
with open(path_csv) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    num = max(l.count(',') for l in lines) + 1
    print (num)
    4

df = pd.read_csv(path_csv, names=range(num))
print (df)
      0     1     2    3
0  col0  col1  col2  NaN
1     a     b     c  NaN
2     a     b     c    d
3     a     b    c   NaN
4     a     b     c    d
```

Similar if header is not important, so possible remove it:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path_csv, names=range(num), skiprows=1)
print (df)
   0  1   2    3
0  a  b   c  NaN
1  a  b   c    d
2  a  b  c   NaN
3  a  b   c    d
```

---

Another more dynamic solution is add values to header:

```
path_csv = 'file.csv'
with open(path_csv) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    #get header to list
    header = [x.strip() for x in lines[0].split(',')]
    #get max number of separator
    max_num = max(l.count(',') for l in lines)
    #add missing header values by range
    if len(header) < max_num + 1:
        header = header + list(range(max_num-len(header) + 1))
    print (header)
['col0', 'col1', 'col2', 0]

df = pd.read_csv(path_csv, names=header, skiprows=1)
print (df)
  col0 col1 col2    0
0    a    b    c  NaN
1    a    b    c    d
2    a    b   c   NaN
3    a    b    c    d
```

Comment: file have more number of lines to be parsed, so it will take more amount of time. is there any other shortcuts ?!

Comment: @Harish - Unfortuantely not :(

Comment: @Harish - Only one hack way - get maximal number possible columns as parameter to `range` and last drop all only NaNs columns like `df = pd.read_csv(path_csv, names=range(10), skiprows=1).dropna(axis=1, how='all')`. But it depends of data, if more columns as `range(num)` is possible lost of data like `df = pd.read_csv(path_csv, names=range(2), skiprows=1).dropna(axis=1, how='all')`.

Comment: there can be any number of columns. There is no specified number of columns

Comment: @Harish - Yes, and it is reason why it is called hack way ;)

Comment: using `error_bad_lines=False`  parameter is reading the excel file  without triggering parse error .is there any way to get rid of that ??